# Update script set all rows with the same value

Tags: php

I am trying to make an edit form in table, and if changes are made I want to replace it in database. I am using table below.

```
<?php
$query = "SELECT * FROM jos_ib_ponude_stavke WHERE BrojPonude = $id";
$q=$conn->query($query);
?>
```

First thing I do is print values in table, this step works fine.

```
<form method="post" action="">
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" id="submit" name="submit">Snimi</button>
<table class="table table-bordered table-hover">
<thead>
    <tr class="bg bg-primary">
        <th class="text-center">Opis Radova</th>
        <th class="text-center">Jm</th>
        <th class="text-center">Kolicina</th>
        <th class="text-center">Cijena</th>
        <th class="text-center">Rabat</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr>
    <?php while ($r=$q->fetch()):?>
        <td><input type="text" name='opis_edit[]' value="<?php echo $r['OpisRadova']?>"  class="form-control"/></td>
        <td class="col-md-1"><input type="text" name='jm_edit[]' value="<?php echo $r['Jm'] ?>" class="form-control"/></td>
        <td class="col-md-1"><input type="text" name='kolicina_edit[]' value="<?php echo $r['Kolicina'] ?>" class="form-control"/></td>
        <td class="col-md-1"><input type="text" name='cijena_edit[]' value="<?php echo $r['Cijena'] ?>"  class="form-control"/></td>
        <td class="col-md-1"><input type="number" name='rabat_edit[]' value="<?php echo $r['Rbt'] ?>" class="form-control"/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr></tr>
</tbody>
<?php endwhile; ?>
</table>
</form>
```

Once I hit submit, I get all values in array.

```
$br_ponude = $_GET['Id'];
$opis_post = $_POST['opis_edit'];
$jm_post = $_POST['jm_edit'];
$kolicina_post = $_POST['kolicina_edit'];
$cijena_post = $_POST['cijena_edit'];
$rabat_post = $_POST['rabat_edit'];
$pdv_post = "17,00";
```

I get all values as I should. Problem occurs in the statement below.

```
for ($i=0; $i < sizeof($opis_post) ; $i++) 
{ 

$iznosbpdv = $cijena_post[$i] * $kolicina_post[$i]; // izracunaj iznos bez pdva i bez rabata

    if ($rabat_post !=0) 
        {

    $rbt = ($cijena_post[$i] * $kolicina_post[$i]) - 
            ($cijena_post[$i] * $kolicina_post[$i] * $rabat_post[$i] /100);
        }

    else { 
        $rbt = 1.00;
        }


$query_stavke = $conn->prepare("UPDATE jos_ib_ponude_stavke SET OpisRadova=:opis, Jm=:jm,Kolicina=:kolicina,
                             Cijena=:cijena, Rbt=:rbt, Pdv=:pdv, IznosBPDV=:iznosbpdv, IznosRbt=:iznosrbt 
     WHERE BrojPonude = '$br_ponude'");

        $query_stavke->bindParam(':opis',$opis_post[$i]);
        $query_stavke->bindParam(':jm',$jm_post[$i]);
        $query_stavke->bindParam(':kolicina',$kolicina_post[$i]);
        $query_stavke->bindParam(':cijena',$cijena_post[$i]);
        $query_stavke->bindParam(':rbt',$rabat_post[$i]);
        $query_stavke->bindParam(':pdv',$pdv_post);
        $query_stavke->bindParam(':iznosbpdv',$iznosbpdv);
        $query_stavke->bindParam(':iznosrbt',$rbt);
        $query_stavke->execute(); 
}
```

Once the statement gets executed all rows in table are same. I use similar script for insert and it works fine. Any help or advice is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, it might be more efficient to use the referenced variable feature of PDO instead of rebinding things constantly. its not needed.

Also you have $br_ponude inside the query instead of it as a bound parameter. That doesnt help either. Since the query string only gets made once. so you are always updating the same thing over and over.

So for for the flaws. Now for the error

With your statement you are updateing EVERY row where the user id matches.

`WHERE BrojPonude = :BrojPonude`

This tells the sql database: Any record where BrojPunde = this value update it with these values.

So what your program does is update every row with every loop.
Now i'm not familiar with your language, but you need to add an extra selection in the where statement to selects specifc rows to update

`WHERE BrojPonude = :BrojPonude AND SecondSelect = :SelectionParam`

```
$query_stavke = $conn->prepare("UPDATE jos_ib_ponude_stavke SET OpisRadova=:opis, Jm=:jm,Kolicina=:kolicina,
                         Cijena=:cijena, Rbt=:rbt, Pdv=:pdv, IznosBPDV=:iznosbpdv, IznosRbt=:iznosrbt 
 WHERE BrojPonude = :BrojPonude  AND SecondSelect = :SelectionParam");// <-- dont ever use local variables.

    $query_stavke->bindParam(':opis',$opis_post_insert);
    $query_stavke->bindParam(':jm',$jm_post_insert;
    $query_stavke->bindParam(':kolicina',$kolicina_post_insert);
    $query_stavke->bindParam(':cijena',$cijena_post_insert);
    $query_stavke->bindParam(':rbt',$rabat_post_insert);
    $query_stavke->bindParam(':pdv',$pdv_post_insert);
    $query_stavke->bindParam(':iznosbpdv',$iznosbpdv_insert);
    $query_stavke->bindParam(':iznosrbt',$rbt_insert);
    $query_stavke->bindparam(':BrojPonude',$br_ponude); // <-----
    $query_stavke->bindparam(':SecondSelect ',$SecondSelect);

for ($i=0; $i < sizeof($opis_post) ; $i++) 
{ 

$iznosbpdv_insert = $cijena_post[$i] * $kolicina_post[$i]; // izracunaj iznos bez pdva i bez rabata

if ($rabat_post !=0) 
    {

$rbt_insert = ($cijena_post[$i] * $kolicina_post[$i]) - 
        ($cijena_post[$i] * $kolicina_post[$i] * $rabat_post[$i] /100);
    }

else { 
    $rbt_insert = 1.00;
    }
$opis_post_insert = $opis_post[$i];

$jm_post_insert = $jm_post[$i];
$kolicina_post_insert = $kolicina_post[$i];
$cijena_post_insert = $cijena_post[$i];
$rabat_post_insert = $rabat_post[$i];
$execres = $query_stavke->execute();
```

}

Comment: you're welcome :-) I advice for you a bit to delve into how Object Reference by value works to understand why the PDO thing works.